# (Checkbox array) reload form and values PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

So i have a form and i don't want to clear fields when form submitted.

I can do this for simple input types :

```
<input name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>>
```

But for array checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="ans[]" value="2" class="grp1" onclick="phaseCheck();">
<input type="checkbox"  name="ans[]" value="3" class="grp1" onclick="phaseCheck();">
```

How I can reload and check which checkboxes checked by the user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in_array` function

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array(2,$_POST['ans'])) { echo "checked"; } ?> name="ans[]" value="2" class="grp1" onclick="phaseCheck();">
<input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array(3,$_POST['ans'])) { echo "checked"; } ?>  name="ans[]" value="3" class="grp1" onclick="phaseCheck();">
```